# No syntax highlighting with SFML in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, block, sfml

As I learned C++ using `Code:Blocks`, I'd love to keep this one as my IDE, but I recently started using "`SFML`" and `Code::Blocks` does not seem to recognize SMFL classes/syntax, as shown in the picture. Is there any fix? (The SMFL itself works perfectly). Also, sorry for my terrible english (still learning it as well...).

Edit : Here's the picture :

[image]

Comment: Have you added the SFML library?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a graphical library in the C++ Code::Blocks IDE, you have two options: do the set-up manually, or use a pre-formed Code::Blocks project. 
I will go over the former, since the latter (using the SFML preset) doesn't work on all machines.

**Step 1: Create an Empty Project**

When creating a new project, choose the Empty Project preset from the pop-up window.

**Step 2: Add the header paths**

Go to *Build Options/Search Directories*. Add the path to the SFML include file.

**Step 3: Add the library (lib) paths**

Now add the path to the SFML library file (lib).

**Step 4: Link your project**

Go to *Linker Settings/Link libraries*. Add the desired sub-libraries (by name, like so: sfml-librarynamehere, for example sfml-graphics).

That should do it. Also, keep in mind SFML provides online documentation for this king of things.